# Como buscar dos caracteres en un String

Tags: java, string

Tengo x cantidad de estudiantes con sus nombres y notas, todo esto lo estoy recorriendo en un For, pero de estos estudiantes necesito mostrar la cantidad de nombres que inician con A y terminan en S (No puedo incluir arreglos, por favor vayanse a lo mas basico)

**Este es el codigo que tengo para el for :**

```
cantEst=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad de estudiantes : "));

    for (int i=0;i<=cantEst;i++)
    {
        nombre=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese nombre del estudiante ");
        nota=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la nota del estudiante "+(nombre))); 
    }
```

Comment: y si no podes incluir arreglos, donde se supone que vas a guardar los datos? como es una tarea, deberias ser mucho mas claro con lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes buscar usar una variable como bandera en la cual almacenaras las coincidencias de las que arrojen los metodos `startsWith` y `endsWith` respectivamente.

```
if(cadena.startsWith("A") && cadena.endsWith("S"))
{
   Contador++;
}
```

Y recuerda que ambas funciones son sensibles a mayúsculas por lo que quizás quieras usar antes algún método como `toLowerCase` para que convierta tu cadena temporalmente a minúsculas o `toUpperCase` para mayúsculas.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma rápida de saber si un `String` empieza y/o termina con una letra en específica es usando `startsWith` y `endsWith`.

Ejemplo:

```
String palabra = "Alonsos"; // Palabra de ejemplo
        
        // Primera letra
        boolean empiezaConAmin = palabra.substring(0).startsWith("a");
        boolean empiezaConAmay = palabra.substring(0).startsWith("A");
        
        // Última letra
        boolean terminaConAmin = palabra.substring(0).endsWith("s");
        boolean terminaConAmay = palabra.substring(0).endsWith("S");
        
        
        if (empiezaConAmin) {
            System.out.println("Empieza con a");
        }
        
        if (empiezaConAmay) {
            System.out.println("Empieza con A");
        }
        
        if (terminaConAmin) {
            System.out.println("Termina con s");
        }
        
        if (terminaConAmay) {
            System.out.println("Termina con S");
        }
```

Resultado:

> Empieza con A
>
> Termina con s

Si necesitas comprobarlo en muchas palabras, puedes fácilmente utilizar este método con un `for`. Luego, dentro de este `for` utilizar una variable contadora que vaya guardado la cantidad de veces que una palabra cumple con esas comprobaciones.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tienes un arreglo con el nombre de los estudiantes:

```
public int cantEstudiantesEmpATermS(String[] estudiantes){
    int cont = 0;
    for(String nombre: estudiantes){
        char inicio = nombre.charAt(0);
        char ultimo = nombre.charAt(nombre.length()-1)
        if((inicio == 'A' || inicio == 'a') && (ultimo == 'S' || ultimo == 's') ){
            cont++;
        }
    }
    return cont;
}
```

Aunque también puedes hacer uso de los métodos startsWith("") y endsWith("")

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

Con **startsWith** puedes ver si una cadena (String) comienza con una cadena dada y **endsWith** puedes ver si una cadena (String) termina con una cadena dada.

El siguiente ejemplo cuenta cuantos nombres que empiezan con A y terminan en S:

```
/**
 *
 * @author SoftMolina
 */
public class Nombres {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String nombres[] = {"ANA", "CARLOS", "ANEL", "JUAN", "ANDRES",
            "ANGEL", "JESUS", "MARIANA", "RODRIGO"};

        int contadorA = 0;
        int contadorS = 0;

        for (String nombre : nombres) {

            if (nombre.startsWith("A")) {
                contadorA++;
            }
            if (nombre.endsWith("S")) {
                contadorS++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Cuantos nombres empiezan con A: " + contadorA);
        System.out.println("Cuantos nombres terminan con S: " + contadorS);
    }

}
```

Resultado:

```
run:
Cuantos nombres empiezan con A: 4
Cuantos nombres terminan con S: 3
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```